# pandas: How to get first positive number after grouping by a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
      a    b   id
1    10    6    1
2     6   -3    1
3    -3   12    1 # First time id 1 has a b value over 10
4     4   23    2 # First time id 2 has a b value over 10 
5    12   11    2  
6     3   -5    2
```

How would make a new dataframe which first takes the `id` column and then gets the first time that the column `b` is over 10 so that the result would look like:

```
      a    b   id
1    -3   12    1
2     4   23    2
```

I have a dataframe with like 2,000,000 rows and about 10,000 `id` values, so a for loop is very slow.

Comment: Is possible some group have no `>10` values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use first fast [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df[df['b'] > 10].groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
print (df)
   id  a   b
0   1 -3  12
1   2  4  23
```

Solution is a bit complicated if in some group is no greater value  as `10` - need expand mask with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
print (df)
    a   b  id
1   7   6   3 <- no value b>10 for id=3
1  10   6   1
2   6  -3   1
3  -3  12   1
4   4  23   2
5  12  11   2
6   3  -5   2

mask = ~df['id'].duplicated(keep=False) | (df['b'] > 10)
df = df[mask].groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
print (df)
   id  a   b
0   1 -3  12
1   2  4  23
2   3  7   6
```

**Timings**:

```
#[2000000 rows x 3 columns]
np.random.seed(123)
N = 2000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.random.randint(10000, size=N),
                   'a':np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                   'b':np.random.randint(15, size=N)})
#print (df)


In [284]: %timeit (df[df['b'] > 10].groupby('id', as_index=False).first())
10 loops, best of 3: 67.6 ms per loop

In [285]: %timeit (df.query("b > 10").groupby('id').head(1))
10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop

In [286]: %timeit (df[df['b'] > 10].groupby('id').head(1))
10 loops, best of 3: 90 ms per loop

In [287]: %timeit df.query("b > 10").groupby('id', as_index=False).first()
10 loops, best of 3: 83.3 ms per loop

#without sorting a bit faster
In [288]: %timeit (df[df['b'] > 10].groupby('id', as_index=False, sort=False).first())
10 loops, best of 3: 62.9 ms per loop
```

Comment: this is nice ! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
In [146]: df.query("b > 10").groupby('id').head(1)
Out[146]:
   a   b  id
3 -3  12   1
4  4  23   2
```

Answer (score 1):

For the last column being sorted case, here's a NumPy solution using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def numpy_searchsorted(df, thresh=10):
    a = df.values
    m = a[:,1] > thresh
    mask_idx = np.flatnonzero(m)

    b = a[mask_idx,2]
    unq_ids = b[np.concatenate(( [True], b[1:] != b[:-1] ))]
    idx = np.searchsorted(b, unq_ids)
    out = a[mask_idx[idx]]
    return pd.DataFrame(out, columns = df.columns)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [2]: np.random.seed(123)
   ...: N = 2000000
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.sort(np.random.randint(10000, size=N)),
   ...:                    'a':np.random.randint(10, size=N),
   ...:                    'b':np.random.randint(15, size=N)})
   ...: 

# @MaxU's soln
In [3]: %timeit df.query("b > 10").groupby('id').head(1)
10 loops, best of 3: 44.8 ms per loop

# @jezrael's best soln that assumes last col as sorted too
In [4]: %timeit (df[df['b'] > 10].groupby('id', as_index=False, sort=False).first())
10 loops, best of 3: 30.1 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [5]: %timeit numpy_searchsorted(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop
```