# How to create a column with first positive value after group by in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a below dataframe

```
id value   dt             first_val_expected
1  null    2018-01-01     2
1  0       2019-01-01     2
1  2       2020-01-01     2
1  8       2021-01-01     2
2  1       2018-01-01     1
2  null    2019-01-01     1
2  2       2020-01-01     1
2  8       2021-01-01     1

df['first_val'] = df[df['value'] > 0].groupby('id')['value'].transform('first')
```

Issue with this query is that it only populates the value where value > 0 and I need this value to be filled for each row.

There is a similar thread, but it doesn't create extra col
[pandas: How to get first positive number after grouping by a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028015/pandas-how-to-get-first-positive-number-after-grouping-by-a-column)

Comment: What if there is no value greater that 0 in the group?

Comment: fill with null/0 then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is replace non matched values to missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then your solution with `transform` and `first` working nice:

```
print (df['value'].where(df['value'] > 0))
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    2.0
3    8.0
4    1.0
5    NaN
6    2.0
7    8.0
Name: value, dtype: float64

df['first_val'] = df['value'].where(df['value'] > 0).groupby(df['id']).transform('first')
print (df)
   id  value          dt  first_val_expected  first_val
0   1    NaN  2018-01-01                   2        2.0
1   1    0.0  2019-01-01                   2        2.0
2   1    2.0  2020-01-01                   2        2.0
3   1    8.0  2021-01-01                   2        2.0
4   2    1.0  2018-01-01                   1        1.0
5   2    NaN  2019-01-01                   1        1.0
6   2    2.0  2020-01-01                   1        1.0
7   2    8.0  2021-01-01                   1        1.0
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) without `transform`:

```
df['first_val'] = df['id'].map(df[df['value'] > 0].groupby('id')['value'].first())
```

**Performance** (always the best test with real data):

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000
L = [1,2,3,4,np.nan] 
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':np.random.randint(N // 10,size=N),
                   'value': np.random.choice(L, N, p=(0.75,0.0001,0.0005,0.0005,0.2489))
                   })
df = df.sort_values(['id']).reset_index(drop=True)

df['first_val1'] = df['value'].where(df['value'] > 0).groupby(df['id']).transform('first')

df['first_val2'] = df['id'].map(df[df['value'] > 0].groupby('id')['value'].first())
df['first_val3'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda s: s[s.gt(0).idxmax()] if s.gt(0).any() else np.nan)


In [205]: %timeit df['first_val1'] = df['value'].where(df['value'] > 0).groupby(df['id']).transform('first')
4.13 ms ± 115 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [206]: %timeit df['first_val2'] = df['id'].map(df[df['value'] > 0].groupby('id')['value'].first())
3.21 ms ± 139 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [207]: %timeit df['first_val3'] = df.groupby('id')['value'].transform(lambda s: s[s.gt(0).idxmax()] if s.gt(0).any() else np.nan)
752 ms ± 19.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: deleted the answer, Thanks for pointing out. But can you explain why transform per group is slow in this case?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - Because processing data complicated lambda function, what is not vecorized like here `first`.

Comment: Oops ;) i forget about that, BTW thanks for reminding +1.

Comment: just a small query, does using transform('first') implicitly ignoring `nan` values in group?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - yop, exactly it need here, ih only NaNs it return NaN

Comment: wow, that's great, didn't knew about that behaviour. Again thanks a lot.